# How to change state of react hook inside other component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

**Senario**

I have a dialog, it look something like this, it have hook for showing this dialog, called `showDialog` , and dialog have a button with `Onpress` method

```
export default function DialogTesting(show: boolean) {
  const [showDialog, doShow] = useState(show)

  return (
    <View>
      {/* <Button
        title="click"
        onPress={() => {
          setShow(true)
        }}
      >
        <Text>Show dialog</Text>
      </Button> */}
      <Dialog
        visible={showDialog}
        title="Record New Progress"
        style={DIALOG}
        onClose={() => {
          doShow(false)
        }}
      >
```

And a main sceen , it also have hook to show dialog, called `show`,

```
    export const MedicalRecord = memo(function MedicalRecord() {
  // const onPressViewAll = useCallback(() => {}, [])
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

  function hanndleDialog() {
    setShow(!show)
  }
  return (
    <SummaryViewContainer
      count={5}
      title={"dashboardScreen.medicalRecords.title"}
      onPress={() => {
        hanndleDialog()
      }}
    >
      <View>
        {show && (
          <ProgressDialog
            show={show}
            callback={() => {
              hanndleDialog()
            }}
          />
        )}
        <RecordItem />
        <RecordItem />
        <RecordItem />
      </View>
    </SummaryViewContainer>
  )
})
```

**Problem**

When i click the button in main screen, change hook `show` to `true` to show dialog, and use this hook state in dialog to set `show` in `dialog` to `true` to show that dialog, and in dialog, when i click button to close dialog, it disappear, but problem is, the state of `show` in main screen remain true, so i have to press twice to show dialog again

**Question**

How can i change hook status in main screen, or how can i press close button in dialog, the `show` hook in main screen return `false`, i tried to change state of mainscreen in dialog but it won't work

**Here is a short video of problem**

https://streamable.com/9mm26t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maintain just one copy of your state in the parent component itself. Then pass "show" and "setShow" as props to the child component.

**Parent Component:**

```
export const MedicalRecord = memo(function MedicalRecord() {
  // const onPressViewAll = useCallback(() => {}, [])
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

  function hanndleDialog() {
    setShow(!show)
  }
  return (
    <SummaryViewContainer
      count={5}
      title={"dashboardScreen.medicalRecords.title"}
      onPress={() => {
        hanndleDialog()
      }}
    >
      <View>
        {show && (
          <ProgressDialog
            show={show}
            setShow = {setShow}
          />
        )}
        <RecordItem />
        <RecordItem />
        <RecordItem />
      </View>
    </SummaryViewContainer>
  )
})
```

**Dialog Component:**

```
export default function DialogTesting({show, setShow}) {    
  return (
    <View>
       {/* <Button
           title="click"
           onPress={() => {
           setShow(true)
           }}>
          <Text>Show dialog</Text>
         </Button> */}
       <Dialog
        visible={show}
        title="Record New Progress"
        style={DIALOG}
        onClose={() => {
          setShow(false)
        }}
      >
</View>
)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it work!! but i have question: Why we need `{}` in dialog prop( `{show,doShow}`) , and why i can use `setShow` but when use `handleDialog` there are nothing happen, they both function? I just beginner, so your answer is very precious  to me, thank you again

Comment: This {} method is known as destructuring. I have destructured the props being received in Dialog component. I could have also used it as 
DialogTesting(props)
and then props.show & props.setShow

handleDialog can also be used the same way. In the parent component you are passing handleDialog as callback so in Dialog component, you can extract it as:

DialogTesting({show, callback})

More on props destructuring: https://medium.com/@lcriswell/destructuring-props-in-react-b1c295005ce0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 versions of local state at each component. You need to keep 1 version of "show" at the top most parent where you care to control this variable and then pass it down as a prop to your child components. Then on your child components you need to expose a callback that the parent will pass down and the child will call to trigger what occurs when the button is clicked in the child component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i still don't get it, in my case, is dialog is parent componet?